# Combine - subscribe to a publisher of PassthroughSubject twice

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm trying to subscribe to a Publisher created from a PassthroughSubject twice and only one of them is executed when PassthroughSubject fires a value.

Here is what I tried:

```
class Worker {
   let stringGeneratorResultSubject: PassthroughSubject<String, Error>
  
   init(stringGeneratorResultSubject: PassthroughSubject<String, Error>) {
        self.stringGeneratorResultSubject = stringGeneratorResultSubject
   }

   func generateString() {
       stringGeneratorResultSubject.send("someValue")
   }
}

class A {
    let workerObj: Worker
    let workerObjPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Swift.Error>
    init(workerObj: Worker, 
         workerObjPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Swift.Error>) {
       self.workerObj = workerObj
       self.workerObjPublisher = workerObjPublisher
       super.init()
     
       getString()
    }

   func getString() {
      workerObjPublisher.sink { result in 
        // do something with result for
     }.store(in: &cancellable)

     workerObj.generateString()
  }
}

class B {
    let workerObjPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Swift.Error>
    init(workerObjPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Swift.Error>) {
       self.workerObjPublisher = workerObjPublisher
       super.init()
     
       loadString()
    }

   func loadString() {
      workerObjPublisher.sink { result in 
        // do something with result
     }.store(in: &cancellable)
   }

 }

class Parent {
   lazy var stringGeneratorResultSubject: PassthroughSubject<String, Swift.Error> = .init()
   lazy var workerObj: Worker = .init(stringGeneratorResultSubject: stringGeneratorResultSubject)
   lazy var aObj: A = .init(workerObj: workerObj, 
                            workerObjPublisher: stringGeneratorResultSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher())

   lazy var bObj: B = .init(workerObjPublisher: stringGeneratorResultSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher())
   
   _ = bObj

   aObj.getString()
}
```

Only `class A`'s subscription block in `getString()` is called. `class B`'s subscription block inside `loadString()` is not executed. Am I missing something?

Comment: what is `.asPublisher`? I'm also presuming that `cancellable` property exists in your real code (it's not in the code above)

Comment: updated now. yeah `cancellable` property exists in real code